# IOC Container Circular Dependency Between Service and Factory

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container, circular-dependency

I have the following classes/interfaces:

```
public class DataExpressionViewModelFactory : IDataExpressionViewModelFactory
{
    private readonly IDataExpressionService DataExpressionService;

    public DataExpressionViewModelFactory(IDataExpressionService dataExpressionService)
    {
        DataExpressionService = dataExpressionService;
    }

    public DataExpressionViewModel Create(DatabaseTableColumn column)
    {
        return new DataExpressionViewModel(DataExpressionService, column);
    }
}

public class DataExpressionService : IDataExpressionService
{
    private readonly IDataExpressionViewModelFactory DataExpressionViewModelFactory;

    ...
}
```

Using an IOC container (`Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`), there is a circular dependency between them. An `IDataExpressionViewModelFactory` requires an `IDataExpressionService`, and vice versa.

An `IDataExpressionViewModelFactory` creates `DataExpressionViewModel`s, passing in an `IDataExpressionService`. `DataExpressionViewModel`s use `IDataExpressionService` to validate data expression strings (user input) and create further `DataExpressionViewModel`s from those, as expressions can be nested within each other (a recursive model).

Is there a way I can resolve the circular dependency?

Comment: Either use a) property injection if your IoC supports it, b) wrap your interface in Lazy<…> for deferred service resolution or c) inject the service locator and get the service when it will be needed. In both cases the solution is that one of the circular references get moved out of the constructor and letting it be resolved after the object was instantiated, so there is no circular dependency anymore.

Comment: Better to know what concrete IoC Container library are you using. It can be useful for giving the correct answer for your container.

Comment: @aepot I'm using `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`.

Comment: seems to me like you want to use the two at the same time. Maybe refactor them so there is no circular dependency? This should not happen with proper design

Comment: It sounds like a design issue. Asking us to resolve a circular conflict without a detailed explanation as to why you've created it like that is difficult. The explanation in the question at the moment doesn't give enough detail to enable us to propose alternatives.

Comment: @ChrisMack - I haven't quite followed what you're trying to do, but it sounds very much like you are mixing a view model with a data component. That's where the design is going wrong. I'd certainly avoid doing that.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thanks - I agree with you on this, having ViewModels mixed up with Services doesn't feel right at all, so I've changed my application to remove that. Further to this I also figured out an answer to the original problem (posted below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After refactoring the application to make `IDataExpressionViewModel` a model (`IDataExpression`), and splitting the service into a "writer" service and an "object creation" service, which removed the circular dependency, I came upon a solution that works for the original design from reading about [delegate factories](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/01/21/software-factories-2.aspx).

I was using delegates as factories for other entities, but I actually had two constructors for this particular entity and so used a factory class instead. Now knowing about delegate factories, I would state that the code smell (or one of them) in my original design was having the service instantiated within the factory itself.

To use a delegate factory to remove the circular dependency:

**Delegate Factory Class**

```
public delegate IDataExpressionViewModel CreateDataExpressionViewModel(DatabaseTableColumn column);
public delegate IDataExpressionViewModel CreateDataExpressionViewModelWithExpression(DatabaseTableColumn column, string expression);

public class DataExpressionViewModelDelegateFactory
{
    public readonly CreateDataExpressionViewModel;
    public readonly CreateDataExpressionViewModelWithExpression

    public DataExpressionViewModelDelegateFactory(
        CreateDataExpressionViewModel createDataExpressionViewModel,
        CreateDataExpressionViewModelWithExpression createDataExpressionViewModelWithExpression
    )
    {
        CreateDataExpressionViewModel = createDataExpressionViewModel;
        CreateDataExpressionViewModelWithExpression = createDataExpressionViewModelWithExpression;
    }
}
```

**IOC Implementation (in App.xaml.cs)**

```
services.AddTransient((provider) => new DataExpressionViewModelDelegateFactory(
    new CreateDataExpressionViewModel(
        (column) => new DataExpressionViewModel(
            provider.GetRequiredService<IDataExpressionService>(),
            column
        )
    ),
    new CreateDataExpressionViewModelWithExpression(
        (column, expression) => new DataExpressionViewModel(
            provider.GetRequiredService<IDataExpressionService>(),
            column,
            expression
        )
    )
));
```

The delegate factory is not dependent on the service, as the object creation dependencies on the service are resolved on creation by the `ServiceProvider`, so the dependency is removed.

As per the article I linked, if lots of delegates are required and it becomes too cumbersome, you can also use `Func` in the factory class rather than creating specific delegates for every method.